# Why using sc.nextLine() isn't the correct way to transfer control to next line of input ?

Tags: java, input

I was solving HackerRank "30 Days Of Code" [problem 8](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem).

This is the code I wrote:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Directory
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws NoSuchElementException
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Enter number");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        Map<String,String> Directory= new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
         //System.out.println("Enter name and phone number");
         String name=sc.next();
         String ph=sc.next();
         sc.nextLine();
         Directory.put(name,ph);
        }
         while(sc.hasNext())
         {
         String s = sc.next();
         sc.nextLine();
         String phoneNumber = Directory.get(s);
         System.out.println((phoneNumber != null) ? s + "=" + phoneNumber : "Not found");
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this code with the custom input I get an error as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)    at
>   Directory.main(Directory.java:23)

I think this is occurring due to the "sc.nextLine()" in the while loop. But I'm not able to figure out why. I had learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/7313260) that I should use sc.nextLine() after using sc.next() so that the control is transferred to the next line of input. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I think it is the `sc.nextLine()` right after the `int n=sc.nextInt();`.

Comment: what is the use of `sc.nextLine();`? You're not storing it's return anywhere.

Comment: @RamanSahasi It is to consume the *newline* character during input (which is occuring in different lines). As given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/7313260).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Documentation:

> `public String next()` Finds and returns the next ***complete token*** from
>   this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that
>   matches the ***delimiter pattern***

And also from the Documentation of Scanner:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches ***whitespace***

And ***whitespace*** includes `\n` and `\r`.

So as a conclusion, using `nextLine()` to workaround the `newline` problem is valid in case of `nextInt()` but it is not in case of using `next()`.

Comment: @Blue I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you. Try it :)
You do not need this line `sc.nextLine();`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        Map<String,String> directory= new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name and phone number");
            String name=sc.next();
            String ph=sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
            directory.put(name,ph);
        }

        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            String s = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
            String phoneNumber = directory.get(s);
            System.out.println((phoneNumber != null) ? s + "=" + phoneNumber : "Not found");
        }

    }
```